# Keyboard unresponsive after SHIFT-right-arrow / Rhythmbox pops up

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, rhythmbox

Recently I'm having a problem with my newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 system (Gnome 3.6). I have Rhythmbox playing radio music, and have it minimised. When I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right-arrow</kbd>, Rhythmbox pops up, the cursor turns into a spinning ball, and the keyboard stops working.

Pressing escape when RB has focus makes the keyboard work again. When I close RB, pressing escape does nothing, and the keyboard will not work anymore. It took me quite a while to figure this out as it happened so quickly.

What makes this happen and how I can prevent it from happening?